# two radio buttons with one submenu

Tags: html

How can I get this

[image: help]

out of this: ?

```html
<input type="radio" name="one" checked="checked" id="1"/>

<label for="1">1</label>

<input type="radio" name="one" id="2"/>

<label for="2">2</label>

<input type="radio" name="one" id="3"/>

<label for="3">2.1.</label>

<input type="radio" name="one" id="4"/>

<label for="4">2.2.</label>

<input type="radio" name="one" id="54"/>

<label for="5">2.3.</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this

```css
table { empty-cells: hide;}
td { border:1px solid orange; padding:10px 15px 10px 15px }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="one" checked="checked" id="1" />
      <label for="1">1</label>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input type="radio" name="one" id="2" />

      <label for="2">2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="one" id="3" />

      <label for="3">2.1.</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="one" id="4" />

      <label for="4">2.2.</label>
    </td>

    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="one" id="54" />

      <label for="5">2.3.</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry :) Took me longer than expected